# How to access stdout from all hosts in a localserver

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

My playbook is as follows

```
- hosts: nodes
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Run Shell Script to get IPs with 4xx and 5xx errors

    script: /home/ubuntu/ips.sh
    args:
      chdir: /home/ubuntu
    register: ips

  - name:
    shell: echo  "{{ hostvars[groups['nodes'][0]].ips.stdout}}" > pip.txt
    delegate_to: localhost
```

There are 10 ansible hosts. Is There a way I can access Ips.stdout from all 10 hosts from my local server.  I'm able to get the first host by the above command. How can I access all 10 hosts stdout from a single variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access all 10 hosts stdout from a single variable?

Yes, using [`map("extract")`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) followed by [`map(attribute=)`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#map):

```
- shell: echo "{{ groups.nodes | map('extract', hostvars, 'ips') | map(attribute='stdout') | join(', ') }}" > pip.txt
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

You'll want `run_once: true` otherwise, yes, it will delegate to your local machine but it will also do that action once for every host in the inventory, which is wasteful.

If you're interested, you can also use `copy:` make it more ansible-y since it actually won't change your file if it knows the contents haven't changed:

```
- copy:
    dest: pip.txt
    content: "{{ groups.nodes | map('extract', hostvars, 'ips') | map(attribute='stdout') | join(', ') }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```